# Squirrel SQL Exception Logging

Tags: sql, jdbc, squirrel-sql

I am developing a JDBC driver which is a wrapper for a web service. My unit tests work fine and I can write my own Java code that uses the driver to do useful things.

When I plug it into [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) it is able to connect and get its initial batch of metadata (properties, schemas/catalogs, etc), but a simple `SELECT` query does not work. I receive an [`InvocationTargetException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html). This means a reflective call failed inside the method or constructor being invoked: this exception always wraps another exception which shows what *really* failed.

However, the error window in Squirrel SQL simply shows the exception name: no wrapped exception/cause, no stack trace. The log in my user directory contains no information regarding what happened.

Looking through the global properties and connection properties, I have not found any settings that would increase logging. I am using Squirrel SQL version 3.5.3 on Java 7 64-bit, Windows 7 64-bit.

How can I get Squirrel SQL to provide more information to help me find the cause of this error? I do not care if it outputs to the log file or the error window, just so I have something to go by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to change the log level is to edit the log4j.properties file.  This file is in the same folder as the batch file that starts SquirrelSQL.

Simply change the line

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, SquirrelAppender
```

to

```
log4j.rootLogger = debug, SquirrelAppender
```